# Is there a moisture barrier I can apply between drywall and paint?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, moisture

We are going to paint a small bathroom.  Over the years the Sheetrock looks as if water has been exposed to the walls.
Is there a moisture barrier that you can put on Sheetrock before painting?

Comment: If it's already water-damaged replace with either moisture-resistant sheetrock, or tile backer (cementboard) which is effectively immune to water. There are membrane systems (redguard, et al), and someone who has used them more will surely be along to post and answer, but they don't reverse pre-exisitng water damage

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a moisture barrier specifically that goes in between the paint and the wall of the bathroom, but there are paints that are made to withstand high humidity. Also, semi-gloss seems to be the finish of choice because it is better at resisting stains and moisture which are common problems for bathrooms.